# Atomic integer es un tipo de dato? Tiene equivalente en C#?

Tags: c#, volatile

Arreglando mí código, un contador ( que no incrementaba) de objetos  en una clase,

```
    class Paciente:Persona , IConsulta 
    {
    public  static int contador=0;
    private string obraSocial;
    private string sintomas;
    private string diagnostico;
   public Paciente(string nombre ,string apellido 
   ,int edad,string  obraSocial , string sintomas 
    ,string diagnostico )
  
  {
  contador++;
  Console .WriteLine ("Objeto: {0}", contador );
      this.nombre= nombre ;
      this.apellido =apellido;
      this.edad= edad;
      
      this.obraSocial =obraSocial;
      this.sintomas = sintomas ;
      this.diagnostico= diagnostico ;
    
      
  }
```

El error era poner contador=++

tropecé con éste tema que parece estar vinculado.
Hay poca info en español y en general hace referencias a otros lenguajes diferentes.
Si alguien pudiese darme una explicación sobre atomic-integer o volatile, me serviría como base para comprender las traducciones desde el inglés. Desde ya, gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Cual es el problema con el "contador" que no incrementaba? puedes poner código? Las clases atomic-integer no parece ser de C# sino de java, demás al parecer se usan para operaciones multihilo. De seguro ya te han dicho, pero aquí va [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Claro, al consultar la corrección del contador en el constructor me apareció el tema en java. Al traducir no lo entendí y buscando equivalencia a C# me aparecieron dos temas: atomic integer y  volatile. Los datos que me das son de utilidad

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu tiempo, no quería pegar código porque ya lo había solucionado. Ahí lo agregué por si a alguien le sirve

Comment: ¿No será `contador++`. El operador `++` tiene que ir pegado a una variable ...

Comment: Tal cual, era así. Funcionó al corregirlo